# How can I code a for loop that grabs data from dataframe1 and adds it to dataframe2?

Tags: r, dataframe, for-loop

I want to achieve a `for` loop that creates a new column in `Dataframe2` that contains for all `òbservation2` matching latitude coordinates from `Dataframe1`.

```
observation1 <- c("ABC", "CBA", "BCA")
latitude <- c(12.4, 34.5, 22.34)
Dataframe1 <- data.frame(observation1, latitude)

observation2 <- c("BCA", "ABC", "CBA")
countries <- c("Uk", "US", "Brazil")
Dataframe2 <- data.frame(observation2, countries)
```

Answer (score 1):

OK, so if it is a homework, here is how one would do that with a `for` loop.

First, we need to make a column for latitude in the second data frame:

```
Dataframe2$latitude <- NA
```

We fill it with `NA`'s to easily see if something goes wrong.

Next, what are you going to loop over? Well, you need to match *observations* from Dataframe2 to observations from Dataframe1, so it would be natural to loop over rows of Dataframe2:

```
for(1 in 1:nrow(Dataframe2)) {
    o <- Dataframe2$observation2[i]
    ... # something
}
```

OK, but if you have the observation `o`, how do you find a matching observation from Dataframe1? You can see which of the observations in Dataframe1 are equal to `o`, but what if there are more than 2 identical observations, like 'ABC' twice in Dataframe1? A better idea is to use match:

```
idx <- match(o, Dataframe1$observation1)
```

It returns the index of the first observation in `Dataframe1` which matches `o`. Using this index we can get the latitude:

```
Dataframe1$latitude[idx]
```

Hope you can put it all together on your own!

That said, if you look closely at `match`, you will see that the `for` loop business is a major waste of time (and `dplyr` here might be an overkill), because instead of all these lines of code you can do simply

```
Dataframe2$latitude <- Dataframe1$latitude[ match(Dataframe2$observation2, Dataframe1$observation1) ]
```